# Paraboiloid from an array elements python

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, 3d, mplot3d

Please help with the problem of paraboloid 3d plotting using from the elements in an array.

Below code gives a nice parabolid:

```
from matplotlib import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import math
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
a=2
t = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
th = np.arange(0, 2*pi, 0.01)
t,th = np.meshgrid(r, T)
#Parametrise it
X = r*cos(T)
Y = r*sin(T)
Z = a*r**2
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,  alpha=0.9, rstride=10, cstride=10, linewidth=0.5, cmap=cm.summer)
plt.show()
```

But I want something like this:

```
th,t,a = symbols('th t a')
rotz=np.matrix([[cos(th),-sin(th),0,0],
               [sin(th),cos(th),0,0],
               [0,0,1,0],
               [0,0,0,1]])
g=np.matrix([t,0,a*(t**2),1])
g=np.transpose(g)
M = rotz*g
print(M)
```

Now `M` is a 4x1 matrix with the 1st three elements to parametrize the paraboloid code

```
[[t*cos(th)]
 [t*sin(th)]
 [a*t**2]
 [1]]
```

Now I want to use the `x=M[0,:],y=M[1,:],z=M[2,:]` and replace it in the parabolid code and plot the paraboloid.

I want this way so that I could do some transformation to the matrix as needed.